# i3wm: Internal keyboard workspace switching isn't working

Tags: arch-linux, i3

I've been using i3wm with Arch for a some time now. Recently I found out that whenever I'm using my laptop's **internal** keyboard, I can't switch workspaces except for workspaces 5($mod+5) and 6($mod+6). Anything before 5 or after 6 doesn't do anything. Also no issues on keyboard side(hardware), and I'm using windows key as my modkey.

My i3wm config file workspace binds,

```
set $ws1 "1"
set $ws2 "2"
set $ws3 "3"
set $ws4 "4"
set $ws5 "5"
set $ws6 "6"
set $ws7 "7"
set $ws8 "8"
set $ws9 "9"
set $ws10 "10"

# switch to workspace
bindsym $mod+1 workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+2 workspace $ws2
bindsym $mod+3 workspace $ws3
bindsym $mod+4 workspace $ws4
bindsym $mod+5 workspace $ws5
bindsym $mod+6 workspace $ws6
bindsym $mod+7 workspace $ws7
bindsym $mod+8 workspace $ws8
bindsym $mod+9 workspace $ws9
bindsym $mod+0 workspace $ws10
```

Comment: It could be that your laptop is mapping these 4 keys to something else. Try to press them to find out their key codes and compare them to the ones generated by your external keyboard.

Comment: @anlar That could be it. How can I compare key codes? or see if those buttons are mapped to some other functions. I haven't manually mapped them, except for i3wm which doesn't work.

Comment: Run `$ xev -event keyboard |grep keycode` and press keys in xev's window. You will see your codes in the output like that `keycode 24 (keysym 0x71, q)`.

Comment: @a Okay here's what happens,
When I press $modkey + 1,2,3,4... in xev window, only modkey and 5 and 6 gets registered. Without pressing modkey all numbers get registered but with modkey only 5 and 6 get registered. So now we have to find out why other combinations don't get registered.

Comment: I would guess that it is because these events are interrupted on a laptop hardware level. It could be that some system functions are mapped to them. May be worth looking at your laptops BIOS settings.